# Which electrical panel is the main and which is the sub?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel

In my home I've got 2 electrical panels. Presumably one is the main and the other the sub, but on the surface I can't tell which is which.

How can I properly identify?

[image]

Comment: What does your meter look like? Does it have a meter main? If not these might both be tied to the meter directly and actually both be main panels.

Comment: If one is a sub, then someone goofed up.  A sub panel should have ground isolated from the neutral, both panels seem to have neutral and ground bus bonded/connected.  Is this in a connected building, two houses together, so two main panels?

Comment: @crip659 It's one house.

Comment: But was it always one house, maybe a duplex combined/sold as one?  Usually a sub panel has a big amp circuit breaker from the main panel feeding it.  Your panels seem to be fed from an outside source.

Comment: No, definitely just one home. This is in my garage.

Comment: I think they're both main panels.  The cables coming into each one look to be the same size.  And I don't an equivalent size size cable leaving either panel and going to the other one, as would be the case if one was a sub panel.

Comment: Can you post a photo of your meter base please, as well as a closeup of the meter face itself?

Comment: You need to replace that Homeline breaker in the right-hand panel. It’s not allowed in a GE panel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you have 320A/400A service. In typical residential service that means essentially 2 main panels, often side by side, as 320A or larger panels are very expensive. Similar to the way 1950s Rule of Six panels avoided a main breaker as at that time a 100A or larger breaker was very expensive.

An additional clue I just noticed, that I believe clinches the "both are effectively main panels" idea is that each panel has two black hots and a bare neutral coming in, but no ground. The bare neutral, of course, touches the panel (or can touch the panel), conduit, etc. so ground and neutral are bonded whether you have an official bond screw/wire or not.

Comment: That's what my class320 meter/400A service looks like, more or less, yup.

Answer (score -1):

They look like two separate panels to me. If one was a Main and the other a sub, you wouldn't have the feed coming up from the bottom feeding the MAINS breaker. The sub panel would be fed from a regular circuit breaker on the Main panel. The sub panel would also be less amps than the Main (example - a 100 amp or 60 amp). Sub panes also have a breaker disconnect, not a MAINS disconnect. As others mentioned, the ground is configured for a main, not a sub panel.
I'd get an electrician in - it's worth a service charge.